# Showing that a certain level set of a continuous family of holomorphic maps is locally path connected

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

I'm working with a continuous function $P: [0,1] \times W \to \mathbb{C}^n$, where $W \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is an open, relatively compact ball  centred at the origin. The map $P$ satisfies the following conditions:

1. $P(t, \cdot)$ is holomorphic for each $t \in [0,1]$,
2. The set $(\{t\} \times W) \cap P^{-1}(0)$ is finite and nonempty for each $t \in [0,1]$, and
3. Let $\epsilon >0$. If $(s, \zeta_s) \in P^{-1}(0)$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $t \in (s-\delta, s+\delta) \cap [0,1]$,  there exists $(t, \zeta_t) \in P^{-1}(0)$ with $|\zeta_s - \zeta_t|<\epsilon$.

I want to know if the above conditions make the level set $P^{-1}(0)$ locally path connected, and if not, what further assumptions might be needed to ensure that it is so?

(I'll give this problem a bit more context, though it might not be necessary: $P$ is a 'period map' of a certain continuous function $\Psi: [0,1] \times W \times D \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ where $D$ is a compact, connected Riemann surface with boundary. That is, a nonvanishing holomorphic 1-form $\theta$ is fixed on $D$, and each component of $P(t, \zeta)$ is a period of the holomorphic 1-form $\Psi(t, \zeta, \cdot)\theta$.)

I'm not aware if there is a general theorem that allows us to draw this conclusion, or if perhaps other conditions must be imposed.

Comment: It seems to me that perhaps $P^{-1}(0)$ is an embedded graph, and probably even finite, but I have no idea how one would prove this.

Comment: You might be able to find a counter-example starting with some $P(0,\cdot)$ that has two zeroes, and let $P(t,\cdot)$ be a copy of $P(0,\cdot)$ whose image is scaled by a factor $1+t\sin(\pi/(1-t))$, so that the zeroes of $P(t,\cdot)$ have positive distance for any $t$, but this distance tends to zero when $t$ is near $1$.

Comment: But then, would we not break condition (3) (much in the same way the topologist's sine curve is not continuous at 0)?

Comment: You're right, I don't see a way to fix that without making things locally path-connected.